# When doing trig substitution for integrals - how do you algebraically convert this into a rational statement?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$\int \frac{2x+3}{x^3+2x}\, dx$$

Is my main problem. I want to do trig substitution but I can't figure out how to make that statement of $2x+3$ over $x^3+2x$ into a rational fraction?

Do I just multiply by $1/1$ in the form of the denominator with a square root function over it?

Is there a general rule of thumb on making statements like these into rational ones I can remember? This is always my hardest part

Comment: $$=\dfrac Ax+\dfrac{Bx+C}{x^2+2}$$  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html

Comment: for your Control $$-\frac{3}{4} \log \left(x^2+2\right)+\frac{3 \log (x)}{2}+\sqrt{2} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Comment: Partial fractions is later in my chapter - I'm having issues with the alebgra side of turning problems like X^3-3x into a square root problem. For example, the professor wants us to factor or do something to it - so that it is a^2-x^2 under a square root.

Answer (score 1):

So we have:

$$\int \frac{2x+3}{x^3+2x}\, dx$$

Remember, in trig sub, you need a **squared** term somewhere. We can do the following:

$$\int \frac{2x+3}{x^3+2x}\, dx=\int \frac{2x+3}{x(x^2+2)}\, dx$$

Now, I'm not sure why you would learn trig sub earlier then partial fraction, since trig sub is usually the hardest.

Anyways, from here, you can to partial fraction decomposition, where then your problem would become:

$$={\displaystyle\int}\left(\dfrac{3}{2x}-\dfrac{3x-4}{2\left(x^2+2\right)}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\dfrac{3}{2}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\dfrac{1}{2}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{3x-4}{x^2+2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

and then solve from there, but if you have not learned it and would like to do trig substition, then you have $x^2+2$, and so you have a $x^2+a^2$ term.

Thus, we can have:
$$x=\sqrt{2}\tan\theta$$

and then go from there.